# capturing stack trace in log file slf4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

We are using slf4j for logging in a java application. Our logback.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="logs/tu.log"/>

    <appender name="ROLLING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/tu.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 500MB -->
            <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 5GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>5GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <!--pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern-->
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.project" level="DEBUG">
<!--        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE"/>-->
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING_FILE"/>
    </root>


    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="WARN" />

    <!-- in order to debug some marshalling issues, this needs to be TRACE -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc" level="WARN" />

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

If an error occurs that we don't catch, we lose the exception message. This is obviously a problem, and we are not looking for a solution like put everything in a try catch. We are trying to find a way to log exceptions that we might not foresee, and that cant be captured in a try catch (like related to heap space). How can this be done?

Comment: `If an error occurs that we don't catch, we lose the exception message` - that will only happen if you don't have a layer that manages the thread execution, and you haven't set a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. I see you use Spring; if you root through the documentation there are several ways to do that depending on whether you use Spring MVC or something else.

Comment: would this catch something like an OOM, or heap exception as well?

Comment: Just to be clear, I am using spring, but im not hoping to just catch something that happens with a controller class. I want it to be that any exception through the application that we do not catch, still gets captured in the logback file

Comment: In these cases the system is already beyond repair, so the best thing to do is emit a heap dump for a postmortem and terminate the application.

Comment: `any exception through the application that we do not catch` - if you're using a framework it will catch these exceptions if you don't (and sometimes that is the correct way to handle them).

Comment: Yes, but if it doesnt go to the log file, then where will it go?

Comment: Well, how did you configure your framework? :-D

Comment: And thats my question. spring is not logging the exceptions. I need it to. So please provide a more clear answer than if your using a framework... if i was i wouldnt be asking this

Comment: I posted my logback file above? what else would I need. Right now, Exceptions that are not caught in a try catch are not logged, so i will never see them

Comment: I am assuming that there is some setting for the logback file that I am missing that will print stack traces that are not explicitely stated: log.error

Answer (score 0):

if you are using controllerAdvice for exception handling, This will help, but not sure if it is perfect approach,

adding @ExceptionHandler for `Exception.class` in Global exception handler class will get all exceptions which are not caught but only thrown as Exception 'Internal Server Error'

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> MissedException(Exception ex) {
        ExceptionResponse response=new ExceptionResponse();
        LOGGER.error("In GlobalExceptionHandler :"+ex.toString()); // <-- This will print error stack trace
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString().substring(0,3));
        response.setError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase());
        response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        response.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Comment: Will this catch any exception that occurs? not related to controller's or anything like that? Ie if we were to do a dump heap, or if there was an oom, would this catch that?

Comment: This seems only related to the webcontroller, trying a simple npe in main did nothing

Comment: as mentioned, for exceptions which are thrown but not part of specific exceptionHandler will fall under this.  i haven't tested this for out of memory exception,

Comment: I tried the above, putting in in class MissedException, and it doesnt ever get hit if an exception occurs. I tried putting an npe in the main thread, and nothing got logged. Is this where you put this method?

Comment: no, you need to put it in GlobalExceptionHandler with @controllerAdvice check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209227/how-to-catch-400-bad-request-in-java/67209585#67209585

Comment: it is working for out of memory exception as well, i found this in my log `In GlobalExceptionHandler :org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`